# MKMapView: user location pin color change to gray automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, ios8.3

This is strange, I have a `ViewController` which adds a `MKMapView` as a subview. There are some steps in the application which when executed causes the user location pin to change its color from blue to gray.

I have investigated in the following

1. there is no place where tintColor is changed in code base
2. used `KVO` to observe tint Color
3. analyzed that in "`viewWillAppear`"(till last line) tintColor is "`UIDeviceRGBColorSpace` 0 0.478431 1 1" while in "`viewDidAppear`" tintColor changes to "`UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace` 0.392275 0.8"

Please elaborate if change in Color Space.

```
 CGFloat mapviewY = self.searchView.frame.origin.y + self.searchView.frame.size.height + 1;
CGFloat mapviewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - mapviewY;
_klMapView = [[KMapMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kScreenOrigin,
                                                           mapviewY,
                                                           SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                                           mapviewHeight)];
_klMapView.mapViewDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_klMapView];
```

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Do you have some kind of modal/window level view added over the map at any point ?

Comment: bhai @Ankit provide some code.

Comment: @Templar nope no subview is added on top of map

Comment: @HarvantS. sir please refer the code above

Comment: `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.392275 0.8` that mean you have 39% of RGB (all three Red, Green, Blue or white scale color) with 80% of transparency (A or alpha).

Comment: I have no idea then. Had a similar problem with some window level views and animations which recolored the whole viewcontroller in the back as modal -> anything was greyed out.

Comment: Are you changing global tint color of view controller on Storyboard anywhere?

Comment: Yes, if you are setting "window.tintColor=someColor" in `AppDelgate`, you might be changing all default tint colors within the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you are using mapView(mapView: _, viewForAnnotation: _) and format it this way.

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
            if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
                return nil
            }
            // rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: this is what is happening while drawing annotations

Comment: I didn't catch what you wanted to say?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so got the answer actually tintAdjustmentMode was getting changed. Fixed it by

```
mapView.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```